# Web Push : firefox endpoint returns InvalidRegistration ID

Tags: firefox, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, push-api

I have implemented push notifications for Chrome & firefox. And testing using curl command on command line.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"\"]}"
```

I'm getting user end point from

```
    reg.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly:true
    }).then(function(sub){
          console.log("ENDPOINT :",sub.endpoint);
        alert(sub.endpoint);
 });
```

end point from chrome works fine

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/cQ4-FwONCH0:APA91bGjycCynoIPO-BVn0h…B9Ck_r5e3hYxcvmzamCWeWbVLDSeY18gtp-NZC3yFMVzFQauE3xQQn4vhVmfkiV3ma-cy4wIv0
```

Registration ID for GCM from end point :

```
cQ4-FwONCH0:APA91bGjycCynoIPO-BVn0h…B9Ck_r5e3hYxcvmzamCWeWbVLDSeY18gtp-NZC3yFMVzFQauE3xQQn4vhVmfkiV3ma-cy4wIv0
```

But endpoint from Firefox(nightly) throws InvalidRegistration from gcm .
ENDPOINT :

```
 "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABXqswopJKVeUQEsBZl12RXsKl01wNvt5T-yqLxgzReRPRdWp7K3xJK58Tmz9YWy3op550irfD3nx-DMnqNKu8BdzvbKgjlksN2_i8VJV-oWnkO8FJwgP-0-m4W9ZVNHYseLLDJ"
```

Registration ID for GCM

```
gAAAAABXqswopJKVeUQEsBZl12RXsKl01wNvt5T-yqLxgzReRPRdWp7K3xJK58Tmz9YWy3op550irfD3nx-DMnqNKu8BdzvbKgjlksN2_i8VJV-oWnkO8FJwgP-0-m4W9ZVNHYseLLDJ
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012164/firefox-web-push-invalid-url-endpoint), that from your Firefox endpoint

```
"https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABXqswopJKVeUQEsBZl12RXsKl01wNvt5T-yqLxgzReRPRdWp7K3xJK58Tmz9YWy3op550irfD3nx-DMnqNKu8BdzvbKgjlksN2_i8VJV-oWnkO8FJwgP-0-m4W9ZVNHYseLLDJ"
```

Remove the v1 part, and check if this solves this issue. Because according to this SO question, that old endpoint has no v1 and work now. You can also try the solution itself and apply the Note part by using [TTL header](https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2016/02/20/webpushs-new-requirement-ttl-header/).